# What is the difference between VSTO Excel 2007 Workbook and  VSTO Excel 2007 Add-In

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007

I would like to know first what is the difference between VSTO Excel 2007 Workbook and  VSTO Excel 2007 Add-In.

In what scenarios either VSTO excel 2007 workbook or VSTO Excel 2007 Add-In or both is preferred.

I would like to learn VSTO Excel 2007 using C# with some good examples and working with the same at high level of usage in real time scenario.

Please suggest me some very good links or websites and provide me some good ebooks related to VSTO excel2007 using C# where i can learn VSTO excel2007 much more.

Kindly help me with any ebooks or Good links to study or learn the same.

Comment: you have not accepted any answers so far. Was there something wrong with all of them?

Comment: google and MSDN are better resources than SO for this type of (non) question.

Comment: I had another think about this question, probably not the best one to use, but we should have one that collects VSTO specific and Excel specific resources for ebooks (not many that are free) and sites (alot more of these).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A VSTO workbook has predefined sheets, named ranges, etc. It's associated with a particular document. In other words you can think of the VSTO workbook as a "smart workbook". In fact I think they even used to call it that.

A VSTO addin on the other hand always loads with Excel, even if there is no document loaded. It's better suited for addin functionality that applies to Excel the application rather than a particular workbook.

For example, if you were going to create a document that when cells are changed, they update a back end database automatically, you would do this in a VSTO workbook.

If you were going to make an addin that allowed you to speak into any cell and have the speech recognition engine turn that into a number, you would make a VSTO addin.

Comment: @Saab They server different purposes, one is applicatino level, one is file/workbook level, you could have both interoparating with each other but that would still need two projects plus a method for sharing data (lots to choose from).

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that in VSTO Excel Workbook all the libraries (DLL files) are available only for that workbook. In the case of VSTO Excel Add-In, the functions can be available for every workbook.